# how to clear subreport value in telerik report

Tags: asp.net, telerik-reporting

I am using Telerik Report in ASP.NET. I have one master report and inside that 2 sub report.
The formate of my report is for each unit I want to print sub report.

All are working fine but problem is sub report displaying only last record only those are assigned last in loop.
I have 8 record in the database. while I debugging my code it assigning proper value to sub report. but on output it showing last two record for all unit.it means sub report displaying same data for all unit.
I am assigning sub report data from function, I am not using any event for assign report source to sub report.
can any one please give me solution about this...?
Thanks

Comment: I think your subreport flushing data when you are coming out from the loop. solution is create some buffer for your data and then assign it to your subreport. Make sure you have configured Sub report correctly.

Comment: Actually sub report data is overlapping. But I want separate value. I don't want to overlap